# RESTEasy, Error 503 and servlet not found

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, resteasy, ubuntu-14.04

I am just trying to get a RESTEasy example to work and it looks like I have some troubles setting up the environment I need.

This is the simple example I am using: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/resteasy/resteasy-hello-world-example/

Instead of running the example on a Tomcat-Server I want to start it on the local J2EE Preview server that comes with Eclipse (?).

Console tells me:

> 2014-08-29 09:01:12.956:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.14.v20131031
>   2014-08-29 09:01:13.141:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of
>   context
>   o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/JAXRS-RESTEasy,file:/home/myuser/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/JAXRS-RESTEasy/},/home/myuser/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/JAXRS-RESTEasy
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.visit(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:80)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.process(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:67)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.resolve(MetaData.java:332)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1219)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.run(PreviewStarter.java:72)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.main(PreviewStarter.java:29)
>   Caused by:  **java.lang.IllegalStateException: No such servlet:
>   resteasy-servlet**    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.updateMappings(ServletHandler.java:1322)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.setServletMappings(ServletHandler.java:1416)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.addServletMapping(ServletHandler.java:900)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor.addServletMapping(StandardDescriptorProcessor.java:1196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor.visitServletMapping(StandardDescriptorProcessor.java:639)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.visit(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:80)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.process(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:67)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.resolve(MetaData.java:332)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1219)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.run(PreviewStarter.java:72)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.main(PreviewStarter.java:29)
>   2014-08-29 09:01:13.167:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started
>   SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8084

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>JAXRS-RESTEasy</display-name>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Auto scan REST service -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- this should be the same URL pattern as the servlet-mapping property -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
            </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

</web-app>
```

And my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.resteasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>JAXRS-RESTEasy</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>JBoss repository</id>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The code itself, though I don't think there's a problem:

```
package com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.resteasy;

import javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/RESTEasyHelloWorld")
public class RESTEasyHelloWorldService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{pathParameter}")
    public Response responseMsg(@PathParam("pathParameter") String pathParameter,
            @DefaultValue("Nothing to say") @QueryParam("queryParamter") String queryParamter) {
        String response = "Hello from: " + pathParameter + " : " + queryParamter;

        return Response.status(200).entity(response).build();
    }
}
```

If I try to call it in my browser I just get:

> HTTP ERROR: 503
>
> Problem accessing /JAXRS-RESTEasy/rest/RESTEasyHelloWorldService/.
>   Reason:
>
> ```
> Service Unavailable
> ```

I've tried various URLs, as I don't really know yet how the format of the URL should be.

Is it just because of the missing servlet? Why is it missing, shouldn't Maven download it as part of the resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.4.Final dependency?

Hope someone can give me a hint, I don't really know where to start digging.

edit:
Console after I've tried @Maleencs pom.xml and web.xml:

> Starting preview server on port 8084
>
> Modules:   JAXRS-RESTEasy (/JAXRS-RESTEasy)
>
> 2014-08-29 12:22:11.378:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.14.v20131031
>   2014-08-29 12:22:11.656:WARN:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:Could
>   not instantiate listener
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:424)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:377)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.loadClass(ContextHandler.java:1528)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor.visitListener(StandardDescriptorProcessor.java:1839)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.visit(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:80)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.process(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:67)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.resolve(MetaData.java:332)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1219)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.run(PreviewStarter.java:72)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.main(PreviewStarter.java:29)
>   2014-08-29 12:22:11.744:WARN:oejs.Holder:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:424)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:377)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:100)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:79)   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:107)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:298)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:791)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1221)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.run(PreviewStarter.java:72)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.main(PreviewStarter.java:29)
>   2014-08-29 12:22:11.746:WARN:/JAXRS-RESTEasy:unavailable
>   javax.servlet.UnavailableException:
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:114)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:298)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:791)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1221)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.run(PreviewStarter.java:72)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.main(PreviewStarter.java:29)
>   2014-08-29 12:22:11.747:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED
>   resteasy-servlet: javax.servlet.UnavailableException:
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
>   javax.servlet.UnavailableException:
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:114)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:298)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:791)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1221)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.run(PreviewStarter.java:72)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.main(PreviewStarter.java:29)
>   2014-08-29 12:22:11.748:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of
>   context
>   o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/JAXRS-RESTEasy,file:/home/myuser/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/JAXRS-RESTEasy/},/home/myuser/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/JAXRS-RESTEasy
>   javax.servlet.UnavailableException:
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:114)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:298)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:791)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1221)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.run(PreviewStarter.java:72)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.main(PreviewStarter.java:29)
>   2014-08-29 12:22:11.780:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started
>   SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8084

Comment: Can you try without the context parameter resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix?

Comment: @asohun: Same result.

Comment: @Feroc - Still is there a listener in your web.xml? If so remove it. Otherwise try adding http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0 to you pom.

Comment: @Feroc - I also updated my answer and added a link to my sourcecode on git.

Comment: @Maleenc - Removing the listener didn't change anything. Thanks for your examples and links, I will take a look at them.

Answer (score 1):

Error code `503` means, your code is not deployed properly. In other words it is not deploy-able.

It's rather unclear what causes your problem. What we can do here is provide you with some working example code snippets. I extracted these from my working programs. So please try to use these guides and give feedback.

**web.xml**

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

---

**Java code**

```
@Path("/payment")
public class PaymentResource {

@GET
@Path("/test")
@Produces("application/json")
    public Response doPaymentTest() {
      return Response.status(201).entity("success.").build();
  }
}
```

---

**Pom dependencies**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

Edit: Here is a link to my [github](https://github.com/pasanlive/sritel/tree/master/payment-gateway) project. Mkyong has [good](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/resteasy-hello-world-example/) [examples](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/integrate-jackson-with-resteasy/) too.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've replaced the parts in my pom.xml and web.xml. But that just results in even more errors in the Console, see edit on my original post.